# what is the time complexity of this code ? (log3n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have this code and I have to know the time complexity of it, I am a beginner in this subject and it confuses me a little bit.

```
void func(int n){
   while(n > 0 && n % 3 ==0){
       do_computation(n);
       n = n/3;
   }
}
```

the function **do_computatation** have a time complexity of 1 then the worst case of func would be O(log*3*n)
is that right ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's O(log<sub>3</sub>n), but that's the same as O(log n). The base doesn't matter, since log<sub>a</sub>n = (log<sub>a</sub>b)(log<sub>b</sub>n), and constant factors don't matter.

**EDIT:**

log(a<sup>b</sup>) = b log(a) (in any base)

n = b<sup>log<sub>b</sub>n</sup>
Take log<sub>a</sub> of both sides:
log<sub>a</sub>n = log<sub>a</sub>(b<sup>log<sub>b</sub>n</sup>)
=(log<sub>b</sub>n)(log<sub>a</sub>b)

Comment: Can u please elaborate from mathematical point of view. How did you get that formula @Beta ?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire: Which formula? That the function is O(log3 n), or the equation? Or that constant factors don't matter?

Comment: this one => logan = (logab)(logbn), @Beta